# JAVA XML child parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a simple XML

```
        <task id ="MyMethod">
            <taskParameter>"Redicted"</taskParameter>
            <taskParameter>"ServerInitiated"</taskParameter>
        </task>
        <task id ="NoRedictedMethod">
            <taskParameter>"NoRedicted"</taskParameter>
        </task>
```

and I want to parse it with Java and I try to print them with the proper nesting

```
        NodeList ParentList = doc.getElementsByTagName("task");
        for (int i = 0; i < ParentList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Parent is "+ ParentList.item(i).getTextContent());

            NodeList childList = ParentList.item(i).getChildNodes();

            for (int j = 0; j < childList.getLength(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Clild is "+ childList.item(j).getTextContent());
            }
        }
```

my results are not right. What am I doing wrong?

PS. I want to print something like that

```
    Parent is MyMethod
    Clild is Redicted
    Clild is ServerInitiated
    Parent is NoRedictedMethod
    Clild is NoRedicted
```

Comment: What are you trying to print? How should your desired output look like?

Comment: I edited my question to answer you note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling as parent is an attribute node. So to retrieve that changes your code to:

**Edited to avoid whitespace characters while parsing**

```
NodeList ParentList = doc.getElementsByTagName("task");
        for (int i = 0; i < ParentList.getLength(); i++) {
            NamedNodeMap attributes = ParentList.item(i).getAttributes();

            for (int index = 0; index < attributes.getLength(); index++) {
                Node attribute = attributes.item(index);
                System.out.println("Parent is "+ attribute.getNodeValue());
            }

            NodeList childList = ParentList.item(i).getChildNodes();

            for (int j = 0; j < childList.getLength(); j++) {
               String text = childList.item(j).getTextContent();
               if (text.trim().length() != 0) {
                System.out.println("Clild is "+ text);
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I found my problem. When it parsed the XML it also parses the blancks so I have chilldren for the first node: "\n\t\t\t", "Redicted", "\n\t\t\t\t" "ServerInitiated", "\n\t\t\t\t"  and this is why when I print them they are messed up. What to do in this case?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also tried to filter blanks wiht regural expression like:
    if(!childList.item(j).getTextContent().matches("^\n.*") ) 
which also works but your solution is way more elegant and generic.